# Feynman Toy Model Constraints on Number of Each Kind of External Lines

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, virtual-particles

(From my homework) In our toy model we have three kinds of spinless particles: $A$, $B$, and $C$.  The primitive vertex  of decay/interaction is shown below:
[image]

My actual problem statement says: "Suppose a diagram in our toy model for the Feynman Calculus has $N_A$ external $A$ lines,
$N_B$ external $B$ lines, and $N_C$ external $C$ lines. Develop a simple rule for determining
whether it is an allowed reaction."

If all the initial particles are $A$ then I was able to determine that $2N_A\geq N_B + N_C$ is a necessary restriction but I am not sure if this basic toy model restricts all initial particles to be $A$.  Additionally, if the model restricts all final particles to be $B$ or $C$ then the inequality in my restriction becomes an equality.  Does anyone have enough experience with this toy model to know if the only initial particles are $A$?  If not, can you offer some suggestions to help me figure out an appropriate restriction for the general case, where $A$ $B$ and $C$ particles can all be initial or final particles?

EDIT: After talking with my professor he told me that the masses of each particle obey $m_A>m_B+m_C$, so that $A$ particles are able to decay into $B$ and $C$ but that reactions that produced $A$ particles as real (instead of virtual) particles are not allowed.